# Interception doesn't work with WCF and Ninject 3.0

Tags: wcf, ninject, ninject-interception

I have problem with Ninject 3.0 and interception WCF method.

I'm using TaskService

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="Fasade.TaskService"     Factory="Ninject.Extensions.Wcf.NinjectServiceHostFactory"%>
```

and my configuration is:

```
var settings = new NinjectSettings {LoadExtensions = false};
IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel(
   new NinjectSettings {LoadExtensions = false},
   new WcfModule(),
   new DynamicProxyModule()
);

kernel.Bind<ITaskService>().To<TaskService>().InRequestScope().Intercept().With(new ServiceInterceptor());
```

ServiceInterceptor implement IInterceptor,

When i'm using UnitTest for kernel, ninject use DynamicProxy object for ITaskService implementaction, but it dosn't work in WCF.

I don't know why NinjectServiceHostFactory don't use DynamicProxy and Interception to return  implementation of ITaskService.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
kernel.Bind<ITaskService>().To<TaskService>().
    InRequestScope().Intercept().With(new ServiceInterceptor())
```

you should change binding to

```
Bind<TaskService>().ToSelf().
    InRequestScope().Intercept().With<ServiceInterceptor>();
```

because in service file .svc there is implementation

```
Service="Fasade.TaskService"
```